# High performance C# library for converting Bitmaps to PNGs

Tags: windows, gratis, library, c#, .net

The .NET framework does [not provide any options regarding the compression of PNGs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4520842/4136325). While the built-in support is suitable for most tasks I had so far, I have high performance requirements which I hope to resolve by using less compression and compensate through higher memory usage.

I saw there are many PNG libraries available on NuGet, but the sheer amount of search results makes it hard for me to decide for one.

Have you worked with one of those libraries and can you recommend one that's really fast?

The target .NET framework is 4.5; higher versions are acceptable.

I have tried:

- NuGet *libpng* but it does not support .NET 4.5
- NuGet *pngpp* but it does not support .NET 4.5
- NuGet *lpng* but it does not support .NET 4.5
- NuGet *ImageProcessor* but it does not have a `Save()` method
- NuGet *NGraphics* but the `GetImage().SaveAsPng()` method has no parameters to change the compression

Comment: For PNGS... I would like to know what level of compression is tolerable? You can change the amount of compression/number of passes attempted to compress; I have used Ifranview and some of it's plugins. They seems to be decent in performance. One more suggestion is ImageMagic, its available at http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php
This would be my second option.

Answer (score 2):

You could try [net-vips](https://github.com/kleisauke/net-vips/), the C# binding for [libvips](https://libvips.github.io/libvips/). It's a lazy, streaming, demand-driven image processing library, so it can do operations like this without needing to load the whole image. NetVips is compatible for .NET Standard >= 2.0 and .NET Framework >= 4.5.

You can convert a JPG image to PNG in this way:

```
using Image image = Image.NewFromFile("image.jpg", access: Enums.Access.Sequential);
image.WriteToFile("image.png", new VOption
{
    {"compression", 9} // zlib compression 1-9
});
// Or: image.Pngsave("image.png", compression: 9);
```

See the libvips API docs for [`vips_pngsave`](https://libvips.github.io/libvips/API/current/VipsForeignSave.html#vips-pngsave) (the operation invoked by `WriteToFile`) for details which arguments are supported.

Answer (score 0):

Can I suggest you look into the [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/), this library has been around [since 1990](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ImageMagick) and is very mature. It is a native library with a .NET version available.

The command line version definitely supports specifying the compression level of a PNG; see this [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27267073/imagemagick-lossless-max-compression-for-png) post.  But I didn't find the exact code you would need in the .NET implementation.

.NET Version https://magick.codeplex.com/

As a side note it does support OpenCL as well but I don't know if the PNG saving code leverages this. (if it does it will drastically improve your saving time)

Comment: I was unable to figure out how to take a screenshot with the library. Therefore I use a normal `Bitmap` to take the screenshot and then use a `MagickImage` to save the file. This increased CPU load from ~4% to ~10%, so I don't have any benefit.